# duplicate rows based on value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which goes trough a big database and checks for first 2 letters , if they answer a certain term they are getting replaced with certain integer ...
i want to duplicate the row which has "RE" as string in the first 2 letters and replace the "RE" to "821" and the duplicated row to "841"
Here is the code i have now..

```
Sub Swap()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, v As Variant, frst As String
    Call deletes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        If Len(v) >= 2 Then
            frst = Left(v, 2)
            If frst = "RE" Then
                Cells(i, "A").Value = Replace(v, "RE", "821")
            ElseIf frst = "NI" Then
                Cells(i, "A").Value = Replace(v, "NI", "801")
            ElseIf frst = "NF" Then
                Cells(i, "A").Value = Replace(v, "NF", "831")
            ElseIf frst = "NV" Then
                Cells(i, "A").Value = Replace(v, "NV", "571")
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Multiple Replacements

- The code is written in this way to allow different lengths of the strings to be searched for (`Lens` - Lengths Array). It is understood that the replacements can be of any 'allowed' length.
- Adjust the values in the constants section. Also, rather qualify the range and its worksheet e.g.:

  ```
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(FirstCellAddress)
  ```

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Swap()
    
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const SrcList As String = "RE,NI,NF,NV"
    Const FstList As String = "821,801,831,571"
    Const SndList As String = "841,811,851,591"
    
    ' Define range.
    Dim rg As Range
    With Range(FirstCellAddress)
        Set rg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set rg = .Resize(rg.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Write values from range to Data Array.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rCount > 1 Then
        Data = rg.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Write lists to arrays.
    Dim Src() As String: Src = Split(SrcList, ",")
    Dim Fst() As String: Fst = Split(FstList, ",")
    Dim Snd() As String: Snd = Split(SndList, ",")
       
    ' Write lenghts of values in Search Array to Lengths Array.
    Dim sUpper As Long: sUpper = UBound(Src)
    Dim n As Long
    Dim Lens() As Long: ReDim Lens(0 To sUpper)
    For n = 0 To sUpper
        Lens(n) = Len(Src(n))
    Next n
       
    ' Define Unique Dictionary.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' '1' is used in 'StrComp' and 'Replace'.
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cValue As Variant
       
    ' Modify (replace) values in Data Array (using Unique Dictionary,
    ' test if first or second replacement is to be used).
    For i = 1 To rCount
        cValue = Data(i, 1)
        If Not IsError(cValue) Then
            For n = 0 To sUpper
                If StrComp(Left(cValue, Lens(n)), Src(n), 1) = 0 Then
                    If dict.Exists(cValue) Then
                        Data(i, 1) = Replace(cValue, Src(n), Snd(n), , 1, 1)
                    Else
                        dict.Add cValue, Empty
                        Data(i, 1) = Replace(cValue, Src(n), Fst(n), , 1, 1)
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next n
        Else ' error value
        End If
    Next i
    Set dict = Nothing
    
    ' Write modified values from Data Array to range.
    rg.Value = Data
    
End Sub
```